# Get Table problem

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks

my function work but the getId() don't can someone explain me why please :

```
public function getAll(){
    $data = array();
    $model = $this->descreplaceFactory->create();
    $newData = $model->getCollection();
    $tabl = array();
    foreach ($newData as $d )  {
        $tabl[] = array(
            'id' => $d->getId(),
            'toreplace' => $d->getToreplace(),
            'replaceby' => $d->getReplaceby()
        );
    }
    return $tabl;
}
```

it return me toreplace and replaceby but the id=null everytime

Comment: Share your collection class.

Comment: <?php

namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ResourceModel\Descreplace;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\Descreplace', 'Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ResourceModel\Descreplace');
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ResourceModel\Descreplace;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection 
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'your_table_primary_key';

    /**
     * Collection Model
     */
    public function _construct() 
    {
        $this->_init('Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\Descreplace', 'Mymodule\AdminPage\Model\ResourceModel\Descreplace');
    }
}
```

Actually you need to add following line

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'your_table_primary_key';
```